# in drupal 7 's view, how to comment without redirecting to content type page?

Tags: drupal, redirect, drupal-views, drupal-comments

I make a view for a specific content type, the path of content type and the path of the view are different.
Now I put a form into the view, in order to comment on that content type. However whenever I comment on the view page, the view page will redirect to the path of content type, so the question is how can I comment without redirecting to the content page but staying on the view's page, perhaps working with ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're going to need something AJAX-y for this. Have you looked at http://dgo.to/ajax_comments? I'm pretty sure it can be used to do what you're describing.